# PROXY, JSON - Нужна помощь с запросами к сайту

Tags: php, json, api, proxy

Привет всем мастерам своего дела. Написал я сайт, вроде живи, да радуйся, но есть одна **проблема** с запросами к api другого сайта, а **заключается** она **в количестве запросов в минуту = 25**. Каждый пользователь сайта делает от 1 до 100 запросов к этому api (*К примеру: http://api.test.ru/status/?status=get*), если пользователей 100, то 100*100 = 10000/60 = 167 минут, чтобы обработать всех, прошу помощи, как можно решить эту проблему используя PROXY, либо например чтобы эти запросы автоматически обрабатывались, но при событии, например ?getapi они прекращали поочередную обработку и отдавали приоритет именно тому, кто вызвал событие.
Вот мой код:

```
$stmtproxy = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM proxy');
$stmtproxy -> execute();
$rowproxy = $stmtproxy -> fetchAll();
$request = 50; //тестовое количество запросов (определяется в другом скрипте)
$proxycount=ceil($request/20);
  for($i=0;$i<$proxycount;$i++){
   $proxy=$rowproxy[$i]['ip'].':'.$rowproxy[$i]['port'];
   $prarr=array('http' =>      array('proxy'=>'tcp://'.$proxy,'request_fulluri'=>true));
   $prstr=stream_context_create($prarr);    
     for($j=0;$j<25;$j++){ // тут 25 - это максимальное число запросов
      $rand = '1231'; //пример запроса (каждый запрос число меняется)
      $myrequest = json_decode(file_get_contents ('http://api.test.ru/'.$rand.'/status/?status=get',false,$prstr),true);
        if($myitrade!=FALSE){ // если пускает - TRUE, если нет FALSE
         echo $i.' TRUE<br>';    
        }else {echo $i.' FALSE<br>';}   
     }
}
```

Проблема в этом коде - долгий отклик (Как раз из-за прокси, хотя я выбрал самые быстрые), 2 - это нестабильность результатов (например TTTTFFTTTFFFFTTTTTT, а если делать запрос не через PROXY, то 25T, а потом FALSE). Чтобы получить список и количество запросов, использую отдельную команду (*например ?request*).